# Class instancing from a static method in C#

Tags: c#, class, oop, object, initialization

I have a simple question. I know that an object of a class must be initialized first to use that (non-static) class in C#.

So (I think) this piece of code does that:

```
namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Person
        {
            public string Name;

            public void Introduce0()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("My name is " + Name + ".");
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var person0 = new Person();
            person0.Name = "Marry";
            person0.Introduce0();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And the result is:
**My name is Marry.** 
 Then I tried to the same thing with a static method:

```
namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Person
        {
            public string Name;

            public void Introduce0()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("My name is " + Name + ".");
            }

            public static Person Introduce1(string str0)
            {
                var temp0 = new Person();
                temp0.Name = str0;
                temp0.Introduce0();
                return temp0;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var person0 = Person.Introduce1("Marry");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And the result is, as expected, the same:
**My name is Marry.** 
 And then I added two pieces of code in my **Main** method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var person0 = Person.Introduce1("Marry");
    person0.Name = "Sarah";
    person0.Introduce0();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

And the result is:
**My name is Marry.**
**My name is Sarah.**
So, here are my questions:
In the last example, why don't I have to initialize a **Person** object to access the **Name** field and **Introduce0** method? Is accessing a static method means an auto-initialization? Or Is it because **Introduce1** method has a **Person** object initialization in it (**temp0**)?

Comment: You've returned already initialized `Person`  instance from `Introduce1` method

Comment: It is because Introduce1 method has a Person object initialization in it (temp0).

Answer (score 2):

> Or Is it because `Introduce1` method has a Person object initialization in it (temp0)?

Yes, exactly. `Introduce1` is a static method, which means that you can call it *without* creating a `Person` object first.

Then, in `Introduce1`, you create a new `Person` object, which can subsequently be used to call instance methods of `Person`, like `Introduce0`.

Note that your code is functionally equivalent to

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var temp0 = new Person();
    temp0.Name = "Marry";
    temp0.Introduce0();    
    var person0 = temp0;
    person0.Name = "Sarah";
    person0.Introduce0();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the second reason: "Is it because Introduce1 method has a Person object initialization in it (temp0)?". You *are* initializing a Person object, which you return from Person.Introduce1. It is perfectly valid for a method in a class to return an instance of that class.